# Block all bots from .ru domains via robots.txt or htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

Is there any way to write rules for robots.txt or htaccess that will block all bots that come from a .ru domain? 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done into how one might accomplish this?

Comment: Take a look at `mod_evasive`.  You can configure apache to block a client if it attempts too many requests within a given time frame.  https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache-tips-and-tricks/modevasive-on-apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with htaccess and some regex. A quick bit of googling shows up many examples, you could have done that yourself before asking here...

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#allowdeny

For example:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from .ru
Allow from all
```

However this is reliant on a genuine referrer and therefore can be bypassed. For a more robust method of blocking countries or TLD's you should implement a separate security appliance.

Comment: So adding something like this: 
    <code>deny from .ru</code>
will block all .ru user agents?

Comment: @bob, you have to specify the Order then specify the Deny and Allow rules.  However, this is very likely a bad idea.  This is going to require a lot of reverse DNS lookups, and if your system sees a lot of traffic it has the potential for slowing things down greatly.

Comment: Thanks for that info, I never would have guessed it. I'll leave it as is now.